# NGINX reverse proxy not working as expected

Tags: nginx, docker, redhat, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to deploy an app through docker containers and reverse proxy it to my destination endpoint.

My docker compose file looks like this:

```yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  monitor.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}monitorapi
    ports:
     - "5001:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: monitor.API/Dockerfile  
  webapp:
     image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}monitorwebapp
     ports:
     - "4205:443"
     - "4206:80"
     build:
        context: ./monitor-webApp
        args:
        - BASE_API_URL=${BASE_API_URL}
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Both of the containers are getting built and running successfully. To access them I'm trying to set up a Nginx server with such config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <HOST IP>;

    sendfile on;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_comp_level 9;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location /monitorwebapp/ {
        proxy_pass http://<HOST IP>:4206/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /monitorapi/ {
        proxy_pass https://<HOST IP>:5001/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

So with that, my expectation, would be if I go to http://HOSTIP/monitorwebapp I should get my webapp. However, I'm only getting 404 and the only way for me to access it is through: http://HOSTIP:4206.

There is nothing in the error logs as well. Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: `there is nothing in the error logs` - which logs? nginx? that would indicate that the 404 comes from the httpd inside the container. Check its logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a similar configuration but with a specifically configured isolated bridge network; AND nginx as a docker container. Then you  don't need https in an isolated bridge network - as it's all inside your single host.

So in the docker compose to have an isolated bridge network you would have.. (I haven't got all the indents for yml correct). Nor have I put in the section for nginx..

```yaml
monitor.api  
  ...  
  networks:  
    - <isol_bridge_network>  

webapp:  
  ...  
  networks:  
    - <isol_bridge_network>  

networks:   
  <isol_bridge_network>:
```

And then in the nginx configuration. Add the internal DNS resolver. And put the proxy pass to point to the service name and port on the bridge network - rather than the external IP address and port. to be clear port 4206 and 5001 are externally visible ports.

```
location /monitorwebapp/ {  
  resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;  
  set $files        monitorwebapp:80;  
  proxy_pass        http://$files;  
  ...  
}  

location /monitorapi/ {  
  resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=10s;  
  set $files        monitorapi:80;  
  proxy_pass        http://$files;  
  ...  
}
```

hope this all makes sense..